# Issue while trying to Login as admin laravel php

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to setup my local debugging environment for laravel application.

Everything was working fine. Today I deleted my vendor folder and did composer install. First I started getting error payload is undefined.

After that I am not able to login in the application as admin. This was not happening earlier. I am not sure why this is throwing error.

username: admin@admin.com
password: admin12345

in DB in hashed format: $2y$10$BgzkwksC4dl8i3IWBGBGLudU1BjvK1giWf7wZeQm7dSOoxkaXfIAG

```
Hash::check($request->password, $admin->password) is always returning false.
```

Here is my Code:

```
public function login(Request $request){ 
        $validation = Validator::make($request->all(), [            
            'email'     => 'required|email',
            'password'  => 'required|min:5',            
        ]);
        if ($validation->fails()) { 
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validation)->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'));   
        } 
        $admin = Admin::Where('email',$request->email)->first();
        if($admin){
            if (Hash::check($request->password, $admin->password)) {
                Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password], $request->remember);
                    Session::put('admin', $admin);
                return redirect()->intended(route('admin.home'));
            }else{
                return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['Wrong password.'])->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'));
            }
        }
    return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'));

    }
```

/*composer.json*/

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.4",
        "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
        "laravel/socialite": "^3.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0",
        "mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib": "^2.8",
        "nesbot/carbon": "^1.22",
        "pear/http_request2": "^2.3",
        "wildbit/laravel-postmark-provider": "^3.0",
        "wildbit/postmark-php": "^2.5",
        "vanderlee/swaggergen": "^2.3.19"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.7"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you regenerated `APP_KEY` ?

Comment: @VibhaChosla. yes I have generated app_key

Comment: `composer dump-autoload and php artisan cache:clear` ?

Comment: I mean before deleting `vendor`  folder and after `composer install` the key must be same, as laravel uses that key to encrypt passwords and all other things

Comment: @VibhaChosla what to do if its changed. And how to know its not the same. I have also deleted composer.lock

Comment: @tonoslfx I tried ur suggestion. Still issue persists

Comment: Have you used `public function setPasswordAttribute($value)` in your  `Admin` model ?

Comment: You need to perform "php artisan config:cache", then "php artisan migrate:refresh --seed". After seeding, try logging it, it will re-generate passwords for users with key in the configuration and you should be able to log in. Also, you do not need to use Hash::check yourself, that's done inside Auth::attempt function already.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov I tried it didn't work. M i missing anything. This was working fine

Comment: @VibhaChosla No I donot have setPasswordAttribute($value)

Comment: Do you have any other users ? If yes then check for them it is working or not.

Comment: In Db i have only one user as admin

Comment: Is there any way to add other user using your application ? if yes then add new user and check, other wise  manually generate hash password and replace it in database and then check.

Comment: let me try once

Comment: @VibhaChosla You are life saver. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Matched my password and hashed password it wasnt same. 
https://bcrypt-generator.com/

generated new hashed password and updated in Db... woooooh it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matched my password and hashed password it wasnt same. Used bcrypt-generator.com generated new hashed password and updated in Db

Manually generating hash password and updating it in Db solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

When I have this problems, I use [Artisan Tinker](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/artisan#tinker).

`php artisan tinker`

`bcrypt('new_password')`

`exit`

Output is hashed password. then I override value directly in database.

Comment: Now my sql queries for getAll are not executing

Comment: : Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'offset 0' at line 1

Comment: Any idea about this error.. These queries where working fine before these changes